# resizing dynamically a CachedNetworkImage image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display dynamically an image from internet in flutter according to its size

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                                fit: if (width >height)  {BoxFit.fitWidth}else{BoxFit.fitHeight},

                                imageUrl: "url",

                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                    CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                    Icon(Icons.error),
                              )
```

I want to have width and the height of the image so I can define which fit I want to use
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need `BoxFit.contain`?